# luis utterance with example of words not be considered

Tags: botframework, bots, azure-language-understanding

I am using LUIS in composer and I use a phrase like the below to give examples to the ML entity "Location".

What is the weather in the `{@ location = London}`
Is there a way in composer to tell LUIS not to pick "moon" as a location in the utterance "what is the weather in the moon".

Comment: thanks a lot vinoth. would you mind giving me an example

Comment: Have you tried @ prebuilt geographyV2 entity ?

Comment: actually i used location as an example only, in my bot i need an ML entity